# Fixing the accesibility of a webserver

Tags: domain-name-system, web-server, availability

I have my server, which is hosted in datacenter, and there is a website and a database installed on this server. DNS servers for the domain name are the default ones of the domain name registrator.

Sometimes such a problem takes place: a website or a database (to put it simply the server) can not be accessed by its domain name. But they can be accessed by the server's IP address without any problem. I guess the problem somehow connected with DNS service, but I'm a little confused about how to fix it.

In the situation like this what steps should I go through to fix it when the problem occurs and avoid (if it is possible) it in the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find out where the problem with DNS is.  I suggest a command like:

```
dig +trace your.domain.name
```

This will search, starting from the root servers, for the correct resolution of your domain name.  If there is a hitch in that process, you may be able to see where it is, though you may need help interpreting the results.

Also, it isn't clear whether this is a problem for just you, or for everyone.

Once you find out where the problem is with the DNS, you can contact the administrator of the appropriate service for help.  I suggest your DNS domain registrar will be the likely first point of contact.